# Properties preserved under Homomophism

Tags: group-theory

Homework question from Intro to Group Theory

If $f\colon G \to H$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $H$, prove:

If every element of $G$ is its own inverse, every element of $H$ is also it's own inverse.

This is not a terribly complicated concept, but I am having trouble with composing my proof.

What I know:

If $x$ is an element of $G$, by definition above, $x^2 = e$, or $ord(x) = 2$.

I know that a homomorphism is defined by $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$;
which leads $f(xx) = f(x)f(x) \implies e = e$, as $x$ has order $2$.

What else am I missing here? Any hints/tips in the right direction would be great! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there. We have $$e=f(e)=f(xx)=f(x)f(x)$$ so $f(x)$ is its own inverse. Of course, you have to use the fact that $f$ is onto in order to show that *every* element of $H$ is its own inverse because every element can then be written as $f(y)$ for some $y$ in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(g) = h \in H$ (here we use that $f$ is onto, i.e. surjective), then $h^2 = f(g)^2= f(g^2)= f(e) = e$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g^2=e$ then $f(g^2)=f(e)$. Because the identity is preserved under homorphism and because $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ we get that $f(g)^2=e$. Then if $h=f(g) \rightarrow h^2=e.$ Because $f$ is onto we have that every element of $H$ has a corresponding element in $G$, then every $h$ is its own inverse.